# Wicked-pdf times out in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

My pdf's generate correctly locally and sometimes in my Heroku app but occasionally they'll time out and I'll see this error

```
2012-05-04T14:53:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/orders/125/invoice_pdf.pdf" for 10.87.41.73 at 2012-05-04 14:53:33 +0000
2012-05-04T14:54:03+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET www.printavo.com/orders/125/invoice_pdf.pdf dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-05-04T14:54:03+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 10.87.41.73 - backerm2 [04/May/2012:14:54:03 +0000] "GET /orders/125/invoice_pdf.pdf HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19" www.printavo.com
2012-05-04T14:54:03+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 127.0.0.1 - backerm2 [04/May/2012:14:54:03 +0000] "GET /orders/125/invoice_pdf.pdf HTTP/1.0" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19" www.printavo.com
2012-05-04T14:54:05+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET www.printavo.com/customers/new dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I am seeing timeouts as well.  I am encapsulating external images in the PDF, which may be the cause of this.  Are you?

Comment: You'll need 2 web dynos and it works

Answer (score 0):

2 web dynos fixes the issue OR used delayed_jobs gem.  Also make sure you include CSS in the generated PDF.

Answer (score 0):

After further review.  You don't need 2 web dynos.  Just make sure to include the CSS inside the application.html.erb folder and your file_name.pdf.erb.

This is my application.html.erb file.

```
<% if request_from_pdfkit? %>
            <!-- css for pdf -->
                <style type="text/css">
                    <%= File.read(Rails.root.join("public","stylesheets","invoice_pdf.css.scss"))%>
                    <%= File.read(Rails.root.join("public","stylesheets","app.css.scss"))%>
                </style>
            <% end %>
```

Any then my .pdf.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <%= Printavo::Application.assets["invoice_pdf.css.scss"].to_s.html_safe %>
        <%= Printavo::Application.assets["app.css.scss"].to_s.html_safe %>
        body{ font-family: arial !important;}
    </style>
</head>
```